# java: decomprss files into string too slow

Tags: java, string, io, gzip, compression

Here is how I compressed the string into a file:

```
public static void compressRawText(File outFile, String src) {
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    GZIPOutputStream gz = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        gz = new GZIPOutputStream(fo);
        gz.write(src.getBytes());
        gz.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            gz.close();
            fo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I decompressed it:

```
static int BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
static int STRING_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
public static String decompressRawText(File inFile) {
    InputStream in = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(STRING_SIZE);//constant resizing is costly, so set the STRING_SIZE
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(in, BUFFER_SIZE);
        in = new GZIPInputStream(in, BUFFER_SIZE);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        char[] cbuf = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = isr.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
            sb.append(cbuf, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The decompression seems to take forever to do. I have got a feeling that I am doing too much redundant steps in the decompression bit. any idea of how I could speed it up?

EDIT: have modified the code to the above based on the following given recommendations,
1. I chaged the pattern, so to simply my code a bit, but if I couldn't use `IOUtils` is this still ok to use this pattern?
2. I set the StringBuilder buffer to be of 2M, as suggested by `entonio`, should I set it to be a little bit more? the memory is still OK, I still have around 10M available as it is suggested by the heap monitor from eclipse
3. I cut the BufferedReader and added a BufferedInputStream, but I am still not sure about the BUFFER_SIZE, any suggestions?

The above modification has improved the time taken to loop all my 30 2M files from almost 30 seconds to around 14, but I need to reduce it to under 10, is it even possible on android? Ok, basically, I need to process a text file in all 60M, I have divided them up into 30 2M, and before I start processing on each strings, I did the above timing on the time cost for me just to loop all the files and get the String in the file into my memory. Since I don't have much experience, will it be better, if I use 60 of 1M files instead? or any other improvement should I adopt? Thanks.

ALSO:  Since physical IO is quite time consuming, and since my compressed version of files are all quite small(around 2K from 2M of text), is it possible for me to still do the above, but on a file that is already mapped to memory? possibly using java NIO? Thanks

Comment: other than not closing your inputstreams (resource leak) and using the platform default charset (risky), i don't see anything major wrong with the code.  how big is this string?  (note, the BufferedReader is useless in the code since you are already reading using an array).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the string is of 2M, but I am doing this on android, I have tested it, it is doable, but takes too long. and I have fixed the close stream part.

Comment: if you have a good estimate on the final string size, maybe you should pre-size the stringbuilder (reduce copying when resizing).

Comment: Look at the edits to my answer, maybe they can help.

Comment: also, your method of resource closing is problematic.  you should check for null before calling close on each stream, otherwise a nullpointer exception could cause another stream to not be closed (e.g. if the GZIPInputStream constructor threw, you would never close the FileInputStream).

Comment: I see that you copied code from my answer almost verbatim, but did not both to upvote or comment. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BufferedReader`'s only purpose is the `readLine()` method you don't use, so why not just read from the `InputStreamReader`? Also, maybe decreasing the buffer size may be helpful. Also, you should probably specify the encoding while both reading and writing, though that shouldn't have an impact on performance.

**edit: more data**

If you know the size of the string ahead, you should add a length parameter to `decompressRawText` and use it to initialise the `StringBuilder`. Otherwise it will be constantly resized in order to accomodate the result, and that's costly.

**edit: clarification**

2MB implies a lot of resizes. There is no harm if you specify a capacity higher than the length you end up with after reading (other than temporarily using more memory, of course).

Comment: Re resizing - when StringBuilder needs to expand its internal buffer, it (at least) doubles the arrays size.  This means that *amortized over the string building*, the characters are copied `O(1)` extra times.  While this is worth trying to avoid if you can, the impact of the extra copying is not huge.  Besides, if you don't have a good estimate of the uncompressed String size, you may end up **hurting** performance by significantly over-allocating the buffer.

Comment: Still worth the try though, I think, as it is suggested by `entonio`. Since I have an estimate of 2M, and on android to save a bit is a lot. Thanks for the comment though, learned a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `FileInputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream` before wrapping with a `GZipInputStream`, rather than using a `BufferedReader`.

The reason is that, depending on implementation, any of the various input classes in your decoration hierarchy could decide to read on a byte-by-byte basis (and I'd say the `InputStreamReader` is most likely to do this). And that would translate into many `read(2)` calls once it gets to the `FileInputStream`.

Of course, this may just be superstition on my part. But, if you're running on Linux, you can always test with `strace`.

---

Edit: once nice pattern to follow when building up a bunch of stream delegates is to use a single `InputStream` variable. Then, you only have one thing to close in your `finally` block (and can use Jakarta Commons `IOUtils` to avoid lots of nested try-catch-finally blocks).

```
  InputStream in = null;
  try
  {
     in = new FileInputStream("foo");
     in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
     in = new GZIPInputStream(in);

     // do something with the stream
  }
  finally
  {
     IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a BufferedInputStream between the FileInputStream and the GZIPInputStream.

Similarly when writing.